Wordpress Plugin - Implements Blocksy Pattern inside a Block Editor Plugin
I'm working on a new plugin on Wordpress, using the Block Editor model.
My intent is to take the "custom taxonomies" and propose them in a loop structure. What I can't reach to do is use a Pattern created within Gutenberg, in particular using the Blocksy theme.
I need to create a Pattern and use it programmatically.
Below is the content of my part of the plugin:
global $post;

function taxonomyLoop_RenderBlock($term){
    $file = __DIR__ . "/themes/blocksy.tpl";
    if(file_exists($file)){
        $template = file_get_contents($file);
        $template = str_replace(["#poster_image#", "#title#", "#description#", "#slug#"], [$term["cover_image"], $term["name"], $term["description"], $term["slug"]], $template);
        echo $template;
    }else{
        echo "FILE_NOT_FOUND";
    }
}

?>
<div <?php echo get_block_wrapper_attributes(); ?>>
    <?php
        $taxonomy_list_args = array(
            'title_li' => '',
            'hide_title_if_empty' => true,
            'show_count' => $attributes['showPostCounts'],
            'hide_empty' => ! $attributes['showEmpty'],
            'depth' => 1,
            'echo' => false,
            'show_option_none' => '',
        );

        $block_style = $attributes['blockStyle'];

        $blockHtml = do_shortcode($block_style);

        if( is_tax() ) {
            $current_term = get_queried_object();
            $taxonomy_slug = $current_term->taxonomy;
            $taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy_slug );
            $taxonomy_list_args['child_of'] = $current_term->term_id;

        } else {
            $taxonomy_slug = $attributes['selectedTaxonomy'];
            $taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy_slug );
        }

        $taxonomy_list_args['taxonomy'] = $taxonomy_slug;

        if( is_single() ) { // Doesn't apply to pages
            $categories_list = get_the_term_list( $post, $taxonomy_list_args['taxonomy'], '<li>', null, '</li>' );
            echo "Hello GUYS!";
        } else {
            //$categories_list = wp_list_categories( $taxonomy_list_args );
            $debugTermsList = get_terms($taxonomy_list_args);
            foreach($debugTermsList as $term){
                $arrTerm = $term->to_array();
                $arrTerm["poster_image"] = get_field("poster_image", $term);
                $arrTerm["cover_image"] = get_field("cover_image", $term);
                taxonomyLoop_RenderBlock($arrTerm);
            }
        }

        //echo $categories_list;
    ?>
</div>

What I would like is that from the Editor side of the plugin you can select any Pattern, where you will insert the specific terms to show the image, the taxonomy title, the description, the link to the taxonomy page, and so on.
I can see the Pattern configuration later, what matters is understanding how to implement the use of specific Pattern in my code.
Thanks in advance.

I've resolved applying the suggested solution in this page: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/i-it-possible-to-insert-pattern-in-php/

Additionally, I've moved the function taxonomyLoop_RenderBlock to the main file of plugin, due to PHP error related to multiple definition of the function. This file (render.php) is used on the template loop, so in this file is not possible declare functions.
